# Count function with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do an overall count function on a set of data with multiple conditions but am having trouble with it. I'm a beginner and tried using a simple count function but am having no luck. I looked into using case when but am having trouble with it. Does anyone know how I should go about this code?

Here is an example of my table:

```
Name  | Date     |    Status   | Candy | Soda | Water
Nancy | 10/19/16 |    active   |   2   |  0   | 1 
Lindsy| 10/20/15 |    active   |   0   |  1   | 0 
Erica | 10/20/13 |    active   |   0   |  2   | 3 
Lane  | 10/19/14 |    active   |   0   |  0   | 4 
Alexa | 10/19/16 |  notactive  |   0   |  5   | 1 
Jenn  | 10/19/16 |    active   |   0   |  0   | 0
```

I'm looking to do an overall count of the names under the conditions that: either candy, soda, or water are anything other than zero(doesn't matter what column or how many, just if one of those three are not zero), the account is active and also when the date falls within the last two years, 10/2014 - 10/2016.

I would want the query to tell me that the count total was 3 and also show me:

```
    Name  | Date     |    Status   | Candy | Soda | Water
    Nancy | 10/19/16 |    active   |   2   |  0   | 1 
    Lindsy| 10/20/15 |    active   |   0   |  1   | 0 
    Lane  | 10/19/14 |    active   |   0   |  0   | 4
```

Comment: Do you want records where one _and only one_ of the three columns is non zero, or if _any_ column is non zero?

Comment: if any of the columns are a non zero

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? I doubt it's both.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the *one* database you are *actually* using.

Comment: My apologies. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (Candy > 0 OR Soda > 0 OR Water > 0) AND
      Status = 'active' AND
      Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two different questions.  The basic idea to get the rows is:

```
select t.*
from t
where greatest(candy, soda, water) > 0 and
      status = 'active' and
      date >= curdate() - interval 2 year;
```

(In Oracle, you would could use `sysdate` rather than `curdate()`.)

To get the count, you would use `count(*)` rather than `*` in the `select`.  SQL queries only return one result set . . . so you either get all the rows *or* a single count.